# c# websocket client unable to connect to Service Fabric service

Tags: c#, websocket, azure-service-fabric

I have a stateless service acting as an api gateway along with a stateful service that is deployed to Azure on a secured service fabric cluster (using Azure AD).  I'm exposing a websocket endpoint (wss).  When connecting from my client app (console application using a ClientWebSocket instance), I'm getting "Unable to connect to the remote server" with an inner exception stating: "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."  This happens if I attach the SSL cert (from my local machine) that the cluster is secured with, or if I pass my NetworkCredentials in with the ClientWebsocket object when I create it.  The endpoint I'm hitting looks like this:  wss://blahblahblah.cloudapp.azure.com:19000/mygateway/data.  When I tested this code locally before I secured it, I was able to connect.  Once I got this deployed successfully to a secured cluster, my client app won't connect.  Is there something else I need to provide from the client side to get through the security?

```
public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(Uri serviceAddress)
    {
        this._clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();

        using (CancellationTokenSource tcs = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
        {
            try
            {
                _clientWebSocket.Options.ClientCertificates = GetCertForRemoteAuthentication();
                _clientWebSocket.Options.Credentials = new NetworkCredential{Domain = "mydomain", Password = "somepassword", UserName = "username"};

                await this._clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(serviceAddress, tcs.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }


        }


        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect once you connected a cookies was established.  I would try deleting cookies from IE history and then try again.  I would also capture results with sniffer like wireshark or fiddler so you ca get your code working the same with and without cookie.  Are you using the same credentials that were used when the initial connection was made.  There may be an association between the cookies and a specific user.

Comment: Before it was secured, I wasn't passing any credentials specifically.  I'll take a look at Fiddler and see what that's showing me.

Comment: Added my client certificate thumbprint to my SF cluster thinking that was the problem but that didn't solve it.  Fiddler isn't telling me much at the moment - I don't see where the connection is being attempted in fiddler but I may not have something set up right in there.

Comment: I do see in fiddler where there's a tunnel to my service fabric application but it's using http for some reason - not https or wss.  not sure why I would be seeing that in fiddler.

Comment: Found the log in Fiddler.   HTTPS handshake to blahblahblah.cloudapp.azure.com (for #33) failed. System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Comment: What is the response from the fabric application?  Is it valid and are you getting 200 done status?  I'm interested what caused the connection to close and was it the server or client (maybe a timeout)?  Http uses TCP as the transport layer.  An HTTP message is composed of one or more TCP datagrams.  Each TCP datagram has max size of ~ 1500 bytes.  So you can see the closure in the TCP (A FIN).  When you are debugging make a time line of the messages.  Large gaps in time usually indicate an issue.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying a specific port and hitting that endoint to our stateful service, as opposed to our service fabric application endpoint (on port 19000) - we were able to get through to our service.  Also had to add some code on the server code to make sure we were binding the server certificate to the websocket listener on the server side.  That solved our issue.